# Android store user data based on login

Tags: android

I have a certain small amount of data that I would like to store and sync based on google id with which user has logged onto device.
For example , In app user saves his favourite book names.I want his favourite book names to available on his mobile / tablet or any device he logs in using that goole id.So basically I want this data to be tied to his login.

Any ideas how we can achieve this ? Is some sort of storing / syncing mechanism available in android or do i need to take some custom route ?

Answer (score 0):

In one of the apps i am currently developing i decided to use the Google Drive SDK for this matter. What i do basically is to create a file in the server, with the entries i want to sync, lets say (this is an example):

```
color=blue
animal=monkey
```

And every time i create new entries, i would download that file from google drive, extend it, and then upload again.

Example of file creation (you can create folders also):
[File Creation](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileActivity.java)

For the sync purposes, all your devices are supposed to be connected with the same Google account, so all of them will have access to that file.

You can check at the beginning of the app if the file have changed, and download it to get the new entries. Or you can (never tried this yet) make create a subscription to a file, so you will receive a notification when that file changed and make the sync.

Subscription tutorial:
[Subscription](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events)

Here are a couple of links you might find interesting:

[GitHub with sample apps by the Google Drive team](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)

[Google Drive Android API guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

Hope it helps!